# SQL Join types and possible minimum and maximum number of rows

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join, right-join

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TYOx.png)

> I have 2 tables, both contain a column `user_id`; table 1 has 50 rows and table 2 has 100 rows. If I perform an inner join, left join, right join and full outer join from table 1 to table 2.
>
> What are the minimum and maximum possible number of rows from these joins? Give your answers in integer.
>
> Note: Do not make any assumptions about the uniqueness of `user_id` in these tables.

- Inner Join: Min = ?, Max = ?
- Left Join: Min = ?, Max = ?
- Right Join: Min = ?, Max = ?
- Full Outer Join: Min = ?, Max = ?
- Inner Join: Min = 0, Max = 150
- Left Join: Min = 50, Max = 150
- Right Join: Min = 100, Max = 150
- Full Outer Join: Min = 50, Max = 150

Are my answers correct?

Comment: Why don't you create the tables, insert some data (5 and 10 rows will server the purpose too,) and see what you can get!

Comment: This seems like a homework question, which aren't appreciated in the StackOverflow community most of the time. I personally have no problem when somebody asks about something for their homework, but when they can't understand why something is a certain way or when their teacher couldn't help them. In this situation your question is just you trying to be lazy. All you need to do is make 2 tables, then do the 4 joins and see for yourself. Don't take this comment in a mean way, it's better for you to learn the proper way and not the short way

Comment: Please give your reasoning for critique, justified by reference to authoritative documentation/definitions. Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question per post. Ask about the 1st place you are stuck/unsure. [ask] [Help] [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) PS Most if not all of these have already been asked & answered. PS What exactly are "these joins"? What condition? Any condition? Equality of ids?

Comment: What is the point of the image? It adds nothing. What is it from? Why are the numbers there? Are the bullets from a form that you have added to? What was there originally & what did you add? Please explain. (But it doesn't seem like there is any reason to have the image.) [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

You have twice been given the advice to create the two tables and try to measure this somehow. I think this is bad advice. Use your brain instead. :-)

It seems to be assumed that you join the two tables on user_id.

### There are three questions that look at extremes in order to find the answers for every join type:

What will the results look like when ...

1. ... there is no match at all? E.g. one table contains user IDs 1 to 50 and the other table the IDs 51 to 150.
2. ... every row matches every row in the other table? I.e. there exists just one user ID in the two tables.
3. ... every row in the smaller table has exactly one distinct match in the bigger table? E.g. one table table contains user IDs 1 to 50 and the other table the IDs 1 to 100.

### The answers

| Join type | case 1 | case 2 | case 3 | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Inner join | 0 | 50 x 100 = 5000 | 50 | 0 | 5000 |
| Left outer join | 50 | 50 x 100 = 5000 | 50 | 50 | 5000 |
| Right outer join | 100 | 50 x 100 = 5000 | 100 | 100 | 5000 |
| Full outer join | 50 + 100 = 150 | 50 x 100 = 5000 | 50 + 50 = 100 | 100 | 5000 |

So, no, your answers are not correct. If you don't understand some of my calculations, think about what the joins do exactly.

One thing is a bit confusing:

> Note: do not make any assumptions about the uniqueness of user_id in these tables.

As you can see from the questions we must ask, this is *all about* the uniqueness or non-uniqueness of the user_id in the tables. It is the key to answer the questions properly and get the right numbers. Well, maybe they meant just that: Don't *assume* there to be a certain number of matches or no matches, exactly 50 different IDs or exactly 100 different IDs, or whatever, but consider all possiblities instead.